# How would GMO tree houses affect the economy?

Tags: science-based, biology

Imagine a future world...only 2,000 people remain, 500 years after the apocalypse. Their world has been heavily modified by GMOs and new inventions. It is almost a modified medieval time, with kings and blacksmiths. One day, I decided their houses would be...Trees! Not tree houses, but instead living, growing trees. If you want a window, cut a hole in the wall. But be warned, it will slowly shrink as the tree grows and repairs itself. These tree homes would last forever, as they constantly grow and maintain their shape. Unless your house dies, of course. These houses would be huge hollow trees, which grow new rooms (branches) and drop seeds (Which can make new houses). Note that there is no limit to land, one must simply put up a sign or flag to claim it.

**My questions:**

1. How would houses that take 150 years to grow affect the economy?
2. How would the fact that you can plant infinitely many houses that take 150 years to grow affect the economy?
3. How would slowly expanding (One new room per 50 years) houses affect the economy?

Comment: With 2000 people remaining, what does economy mean?

Comment: The amount of people is rapidly expanding, and there is already a little bit of money circulating. In 150 years, there could easily be many times more people

Comment: why would they care about in what type of house they are living in if there's only 2k of them? Each one of them could live in different type of house (time period and materials) and they would never repeat.

Comment: "*How would houses that take 150 years to grow affect the economy?*"  A house that takes 150 years to build isn't very useful when you need shelter **now**.

Comment: With 2000 people left I don't think finding shelter will be any kind of problem. There will literally be so much available shelter that people won't know what to do with it (even if only as caves). Making homes out of trees seems very arbitrary. It also seems to me that hollowing out a large part of the interior of a tree would result in it dying, since it does have to transport water and minerals back and forth between its roots and leaves almost constantly. Which having a house in the middle of it will disrupt (significantly? Depends on how much space is used).

Comment: The enormous apocalypse destroyed everything, and the world is back to forests and plains

Comment: People didn't start building houses until the modern age. Caves, huts, and tents seem a lot more practical; less effort to make and get the resources for, or relocatable, or fast to make/find. There may be a better reason for them living in trees, like some kind of overwhelming danger when being on the ground at night?

Comment: Oh btw you should consider that the fact that they last forever has little economic value over them lasting say 50 years, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity

Comment: In 50 years, the house will be bigger

Comment: Is the Planet already populated with those house-trees?

Comment: If, after 500 years, the population has *grown* to a mere 2000, then there seem to be bigger problems than economics. Like (severe) inbreeding over those preceding 20 generations. And an apparently very harsh life that keeps population growth very, very low.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms This is a ["Develop my high-concept"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/) type of question. Those types of questions are much too broad to be answered. It also points to a question about your authoring needs an answer: **why** do you want to have this particular high concept in your story? What is your **goal** or **purpose** of including it? If it just for flavour? It is because it makes for a neat mental image of what your fictional world is like? Or is it **important for the narrative**? Is your story **stuck** unless you have it? (continued)

Comment: (Continued) My point is: do not throw stuff into your story/world if you do not know **why** you want it there. Remember that it is your **story** that drives your world-building... it is not your world that drives your story.

Answer (score 4):

150 years is too slow to keep up with population growth.
More likely, new families will look for other house-trees, or build regular houses (or huts, or lean-to's) from regular trees (or from branches of house-trees).

If tree houses are viewed as superior, then only the rich will live there. 
If people refuse to live in anything but tree houses, there will be cramped conditions, and fights over who gets to move into newly sprouted room. 
Either you will have to restrain the birth rate to keep up with natural tree growth, or cast out some members.

But those outcasts will start building regular houses, b/c survival instinct will overcome the cultural and social need to live in a tree house.

Finally, 2000 people will not give you much of an economy. Economy means trade and specialization, and there is not enough people to specialize into anything more advanced than blacksmithing and pottery. So you will have 1900 farmers (or hunter/gatherers), 100 craftsmen, a few healers and one chief. There will be no need for soldiers (since there is nobody to fight). There is nothing to fight over -- there are plenty of lands and resources. The only limited resource would be your trees.

Comment: I think this answer sums up the situation pretty well. Tree houses are not going to add much value, and the question of how it would impact the "economy" is; not much. If there is an economy at all, and there is a shortage of houses, people will just make other kinds of dwellings since resources are so abundant (except tree houses). It might be best to think of tree houses as a luxury product, rather than as a necessity.

Comment: The trees is very doubtful limited resource as OP state that the tree is GMO. How can you GMO tree? Either to grow (mature) much faster to usable size or to have much larger rate of seeds growing into new trees. Both of these in very short period remove said trees from "limited resource" section.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY, the OP said the people alive are technologically equivalent to Medieval times. They almost certainly have no control over what kind of GMO the trees are. Maybe they are just GMO'd to live long or be big? As I read it the modifications were made before the apocalypse. It doesn't say that they have been modified to grow fast or reproduce quickly, so I would not assume that they have been.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I just assumed that the GMO was done so that the trees that grow big were designed to grow faster to their large size (so you take gigant sequoia and speed up it's growth rather than take regular growing tree and make it grow bigger). From a GModder point of view you rather take something that have all desired characteristic and just change one rather than add something new to organism.

Comment: No, they are GMO designed to actually grow wider, with shapes and formations that make it a house